# How to match paragraphs containing a specific pattern with regex?

Tags: python, regex

I have the following paragraphs :

```
This is paragraph #1
New-York, London, Paris, Berlin
Some other text
End of paragraph

This is paragraph #2
London, Paris
End of paragraph

This is paragraph #3
New-York, Paris, Berlin
Some other text
End of paragraph

This is paragraph #4
End of paragraph

This is paragraph #5
Paris, Berlin
Some other text
End of paragraph
```

How can I, with a regex, match the paragraphs containing e.g. New-York (#1 and #3) or London (#1, #2) ? or even New-York AND Berlin (#1, #3) ?

I have found an answer in S.O.

[How match a paragraph using regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18568105/how-match-a-paragraph-using-regex)

which allows me to match the paragraphs (all the text between two blank lines).

But I cannot figure (my regex skills are… limited) how to match the paragraphs containing a specific pattern, and only those paragraphs.

Thanks in advance for your help

NB : the idea is to use the answer in the Editorial IOS app to fold the answers NOT containing the pattern.

Comment: Which programming language do you use? It might be easier to split the paragraphs first (on empty lines) and then look for `New-York` in them.

Comment: Which flavor of regex? Python? Do you have to use regex in one line? The answer you link to splits on "\n\n".

Comment: @kabanus : Python

Comment: @Jan : I do not want to split the paragraphs : I want to keep thr entire paragraphs containing the specified pattern, and those paragraphs only.

Comment: Just a couple of raw ideas: https://regex101.com/r/pWP0CK/1, https://regex101.com/r/pWP0CK/2 and https://regex101.com/r/pWP0CK/3

Comment: A bit optimized... https://regex101.com/r/BWZkb9/1/ Now, you see it is better to resort to the code to check for things like the city names. Or at least run 2 separate regexes, one to extract and the other to filter. Or use the `regex` module as Jan suggests.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew : superb ! Could you make it an answer in order to allow me to to accept it ? (I have thanked Jan by signaling his answer was useful). Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see you might have no access to the Python code itself if you plan to use the pattern in the Editorial iOS app.

Then, all I can suggest  is the pattern like

```
(?m)^(?=.*(?:\r?\n(?!\r?\n).*)*?\bNew-York\b)(?=.*(?:\r?\n(?!\r?\n).*)*?\bBerlin\b).*(?:\r?\n(?!\r?\n).*)*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BWZkb9/1/). Basically, we only match from the start of the line (`^` with `(?m)` modifier), we check if there are `New-York` and `Berlin` as whole words (due to the `\b` word boundaries) anywhere on the lines before the first double line break and if present, match these lines.

**Details**

- `(?m)^` - start of the line
- `(?=.*(?:\r?\n(?!\r?\n).*)*?\bNew-York\b)` - a positive lookahead that make sure there is a whole word `New-York` anywhere after 0+ chars other than line break chars (`.*`) optionally followed with 0+ consecutive sequences of CRLF/LF line breaks not followed with another CRLF/LF line breaks followed with the rest of the line
- `(?=.*(?:\r?\n(?!\r?\n).*)*?\bBerlin\b)` - a whole word `Berlin` anywhere after 0+ chars other than line break chars (`.*`) optionally followed with 0+ consecutive sequences of CRLF/LF line breaks not followed with another CRLF/LF line breaks followed with the rest of the line
- `.*` - match the line
- `(?:\r?\n(?!\r?\n).*)*` - match 0+ consecutive occurrences of:

  - `\r?\n(?!\r?\n)` - a line break (CRLF or LF) not followed with another CRLF or LF
  - `.*` - the rest of the line.

Answer (score 2):

Using the [**newer `regex` module**](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex/) which supports empty splits:

```
import regex as re

string = """
This is paragraph #1
New-York, London, Paris, Berlin
Some other text
End of paragraph

This is paragraph #2
London, Paris
End of paragraph

This is paragraph #3
New-York, Paris, Berlin
Some other text
End of paragraph

This is paragraph #4
End of paragraph

This is paragraph #5
Paris, Berlin
Some other text
End of paragraph
"""

rx = re.compile(r'^$', flags = re.MULTILINE | re.VERSION1)

needle = 'New-York'

interesting = [part 
    for part in rx.split(string)
    if needle in part]

print(interesting)
# ['\nThis is paragraph #1\nNew-York, London, Paris, Berlin\nSome other text\nEnd of paragraph\n', '\nThis is paragraph #3\nNew-York, Paris, Berlin\nSome other text\nEnd of paragraph\n']
```

Comment: 1) thank you for your answer 2) I tried it in Pythonista (same developer as Editorial ; btw, Editorial can use Python scripts) and ran into problems because - I think - it does not seem to support the newer regex module 3) your answer seems to mean that there is no pure regex (PCRE) solution.